# Python PIL displays gray window

Tags: android, python, adb, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get android screenshots from ADB and displaying them in a window using Python and PIL (it could be Pillow, I don't know exactly)

The code is very simple:

```
class Viewer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.title('ADB connection')

        self.pane = None
        self.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self):
        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as nul:
            subprocess.check_call([adb, adb_option, 'shell', 'screencap -p /sdcard/scr.png'])
            subprocess.check_call([adb, adb_option, 'pull', '/sdcard/scr.png'], stdout=nul)

        tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('scr.png'))

        if not self.pane:
            self.pane = Tkinter.Label(self.root, image = tkimg)
            self.pane.pack()

        else:
            self.pane.configure(image = tkimg)
        self.root.after(timeout, self.update)
```

I've found a lot of guides and the code is roughly the same everywhere.

In my case it doesn't work: the image is loaded, the width and height match, and a window of the right size is displayed, but no image is displayed. The file exists, and contains the actual screenshot. If I debug the program, the image object seems to be Ok (at least the size, I can't read the image data)

It seems to be a problem in decoding or displaying the PNG data. Or maybe I'm missing some parameters, or some function calls?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without explanation. That's exactly what we all need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally understood the problem: python was garbage collecting the image before it could be displayed.

I've changed `tkimg` to `self.tkimg` and now it works.

Thanks anyway.